# How can I get the value of a text variable that have the same name of a integer variable in VBA?

Tags: vba, scope, userform

I have an userform that get some values..and I try to use a loop to get the values of theses variables that I get through a textbox, so I try to get the value of a variable through other variable(text) that have the same name of a number variable.. Anyone can help me to do this?
Example of my variables are: amountfra11a,amountfra12a...(these are the name of my textbox)

follows the code:

```
 Private Sub OKTESTE_Click()

  Dim b As Integer


For i = 1 To 1

    a = "amountfra1" & i & "a.value"
    b = CInt(a)


    If b = 10 Then
        c = d
    End If

Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can get the texbox values via the `Controls` collection of the UserForm:

```
Private Sub OKTESTE_Click()
    Dim i, nm, a
    For i = 11 To 12 'for example
        nm = "amountfra" & i & "a"
        a = Me.Controls(nm).Text
        MsgBox nm & " = " & a
    Next

End Sub
```